# How to get running sum of a column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Hi I have a column with name Qty from table Bills
i want a column that show the running sum of Qty column like this :

```
Qty   Run_Sum
1      1
2      3
3      6
4      10
5      15
```

Suggest me some appropriate method to make running some thankx

Comment: How is that running sum? 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34.....[The fibonacci series] would be an example of running sum.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Comment: @user1448783 do you want data in select query for report purpose or you want a column in your table?

Comment: @user1448783 have you try my answer ?

Answer (score 12):

if you RDBMS supports window function,

for `SQL Server 2012`

```
SELECT  Qty,
        SUM(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY Qty) AS CumulativeTOTAL
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bca9/2)

for `SQL Server 2008`

```
SELECT a.Qty, (SELECT SUM(b.Qty)
               FROM   TableName b
               WHERE  b.Qty <= a.Qty)
FROM   TableName a
ORDER  BY a.Qty;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bca9/2)

Comment: I think subquery would be slow

Answer (score 12):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bafd76/1)

```
SELECT Qty,
SUM(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY Qty) Run_Sum
FROM t ORDER BY Qty
```

For SQLServer prior to 2012:

```
select Qty,
(select sum(Qty) from t where Qty<=t1.Qty)
from t t1 order by Qty
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bafd76/2)

Or also you can do it without subquery:

```
select t1.Qty, sum(t2.Qty)
from t t1 
join t t2 on (t1.Qty>=t2.Qty)
group by t1.Qty
order by t1.Qty
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bafd76/6)

Comment: added query for prior SQLServer versions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but i was referring only to versions of sql server `:)`

Comment: Your answer only works, if `quantity` is unique. How would that work, if there are duplicate `quantities`?

Comment: @Valex I didn't find anything unique in solution #1 which everyone is mentioning that it won't work prior version of SQL Server 2012; this also work in SQL Server 2008 R2+ (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bafd7/6). Am I missing anything?

Comment: @AnujTripathi `OVER` clause is implemented starting from 
SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Valex Thanks for prompt response. Apparently, I've started my SQL journey from SQL Server 2008 :) +1 though !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample using Oracle/analytical functions:

```
select id, qty, sum(qty) over(order by id asc) run_sum
from test;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d149/1

Comment: Dear i am using sql server please provide some sample code in sql server

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing that out. Here's an updated query (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ac1f/5): `select id, qty, (select sum(qty)
                   from test
                  where id <= t.id) run_sum
  from test t;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
DECLARE @TEMP table
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    QUANTITY int
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 1

SELECT t.QUANTITY AS Qty, SUM(t1.QUANTITY) AS Run_Sum
FROM @TEMP t
INNER JOIN @TEMP t1
ON t1.ID <= t.ID
GROUP BY t.ID, t.QUANTITY
ORDER BY t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (
  select top 1 Qty, Qty as RunningSum
  from Bills
  order by Qty

  union all

  select t.Qty, cte.RunningSum + t.Qty
  from cte
  inner join Bills t on cte.Qty + 1 = t.Qty
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

@mahmud:
See what this gives

```
DECLARE @Bills table
(
    QUANTITY int
)

INSERT INTO @Bills
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT -5 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
select 1

;with cte as (
  select top 1 QUANTITY, QUANTITY as RunningSum
  from @Bills
  order by QUANTITY

  union all

  select t.QUANTITY, cte.RunningSum + t.QUANTITY
  from cte
  inner join @Bills t on cte.QUANTITY + 1 = t.QUANTITY
)
select * from cte
```