# Field added to django querysets not working in django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-tables2

I have a set of imported bank account entries that are oredered by date and sequence number within each date.

I'm using django-tables2 to display the data, to which I'm adding a running total column that I calculate before rendering the view.

To do this I'm trying to add a field to the query set with the following code:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from .models import Bank, BankImportFile, ImportFileEntry
... other imports

class BankListingTable(tables.Table):
    memo = tables.Column(verbose_name = 'Description')
    total = tables.Column(verbose_name = 'Running Total')
    class Meta:
        model = ImportFileEntry
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}

def bank_listing(request, bankname):
    bank = get_object_or_404(Bank, pk=bankname)
    qs = ImportFileEntry.objects.filter(account=Bank(bank)).order_by('date', 'seq')
    total = 0
    for row in qs:
        total += row.amount
        row.total = total
    table =  BankListingTable(qs)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'banking/bank_transactions.html', {'table': table, 'bank': bank})
```

If I step through this code in `pdb` I can examine both `row.total` and `qs[<row number>].total` and they appear to have the correct data.

Yet in the rendered table all I get in the total column is `--`

If I convert my `queryset` to a list and leave everything else unchanged it works:

```
def bank_listing(request, bankname):
    bank = get_object_or_404(Bank, pk=bankname)
    qs = ImportFileEntry.objects.filter(account=Bank(bank)).order_by('date', 'seq')
    qs = list(qs)    # ADDED THIS LINE AND IT WORKS
    total = 0
    for row in qs:
        total += row.amount
        row.total = total
    table =  BankListingTable(qs)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'banking/bank_transactions.html', {'table': table, 'bank': bank})
```

My `queryset` is large as it is a 9-year history of a business bank account so it seems very inefficient to copy it to a `list`.

I've seen other examples on `StackOverflow` that seem to imply my original code should work and pdb testing implies it should. Is this something in `django-tables2`?

Comment: Hello! I tried doing what you did (without the conversion to ``list``) and it works fine. Probably you are missing something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, what you did is working in my case. However, I wouldn't recommend evaluating the query with the `for` loop since this will load your queryset to memory (it actually has the same effect as using `list`). Instead, I'd recommend adding an extra row to your query that would contain the running sum.

To do do that you should use the [`extra` queryset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) to add the extra field to your queryset. To find out how to get the running total with SQL you can check the answer to this question: [How to get running sum of a column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953294/how-to-get-running-sum-of-a-column-in-sql-server)

Also, since you mention that your queryset is large you *should* add pagination to your table -- and you will *not* benefit from pagination if you evaluate your queryset with the `for-loop`. Feel free to ask again if you have trouble implementing the `extra()` method.

*Update*: To answer OP's comment (I am not sure about the names of your tables & fields but I'll make a guess:

```
SELECT amount, (
    select sum(amount) FROM ImportFileEntry ife1 where ife1.date < ife.date
  ) + (
    select sum(amount) FROM ImportFileEntry ife2 where ife2.date = ife.date and ife2.seq < ife.seq
  ) as running_total  FROM ImportFileEntry ife order by ife.date, ife.seq
```

One (complex) query -- the `as running_total` would be what the `extra()` queryset method would create :)

Comment: I couldn't see a solution in the examples there. It seems to get a running total on each record in a query I'd need to run a subquery that calculates <sum of all amounts `UP TO` and including this record> which would be n queries for n records. Also my `UP TO` is non trivial as my sort order is date then seq. I'm using pgSQL. Thanks for your reply and any further advice you can offer

Comment: Yes it would be n queries for n rows (actually it will be *one* complex query). However, if you use pagination as I recommended you'd have a page with 25 rows even if you have millions of rows in your database. On the other hand, if you evaluate the queryset using the for loop or the list you'd need to put everything to your memory.

Comment: Can you give me a hint or a link for the form of the `one complex query` that adds field running_total = sum of `amount` of all records with (date < this record's date) plus those with (date = this record's date AND seq <= this records seq)