# MySQL Select maximum concurrent calls in a time period

Tags: mysql, date, concurrency, overlap

I have a table storing all the calls that pass through the system.

The columns I am interested in are just calldate and callend which are the start and end times of a call.

I want to select how many concurrent calls were in progress at the same time.

I have a query which returns all the over lapping calls but this doesn't quite give me what I want.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(t.calldate)+300)/600)*600) AS `TIME`,
     MAX(t.overlaps)
FROM(
    SELECT x.id,
           x.calldate,
           COUNT(y.id) overlaps
    FROM cdr x
    LEFT
    JOIN cdr y
      ON y.id <> x.id
     AND y.calldate < x.callend
     AND y.callend > x.calldate
     AND y.calldate BETWEEN '2015-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-01 23:59:59'
    WHERE
        x.calldate BETWEEN '2015-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-01 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY 
        x.id
) t
GROUP BY `TIME`;
```

This is returning me some of the right things but because its returning all the overlapping calls it may actually overlap with calls that finished before that time so some of the numbers are too high.

```
Call    08:00    08:05    08:10    08:15    08:20    08:25
1         |-----------------|
2                  |-----------------|
3      |--------------|
4             |--------------------------------------|
5                               |--------------|
6                    |------------------------------------|    
       1  2   3    4 5 4     3  4     3         2     1   0
```

So for example that would return 5 because its looking at the call id rather than the dates, I'm just not sure how to change it get it to use the dates properly.

I'm probably missing something simple but it's been a long day.

**EDIT**

Using edTarik's answer this works:

```
SELECT y.`Interval`,
         @lines := CAST((@lines + y.t) AS INT) as TotayQuantity
FROM 
    (SELECT @lines := 0) init,
    (
        SELECT 
            SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(x.cd)+300)/600)*600) as `Interval`, 
            SUM(x.t) as t 
        FROM 
            (   
                SELECT 
                    calldate as cd, 
                    1 as t 
                FROM cdr c
                WHERE 
                    calldate BETWEEN '2015-05-04 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-04 23:59:59'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                    callend as cd, 
                    -1 as t 
                FROM cdr c
                WHERE 
                    callend BETWEEN '2015-05-04 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-04 23:59:59'
                ORDER BY cd
            ) x 
        GROUP BY `Interval`
    ) y
```

Comment: This looks just about right - but provide proper DDLs and a desired result so we can play too.

Comment: It looks about right but currently if I were to run it with the data for 08:15 I would get 4 back because call 6 overlaps with 4 calls, it should return 3 because there is a max of 3 calls between 08:15 and 08:20. Does that make sense? I'll try and get some DDLs for you later this evening.

Comment: Did you try my solution? I had the exact same problem and it solved it for me.

Comment: @edTarik Yes I did which looked like it might have been doing it correctly from midnight till around 8:30 when all the numbers started going negative.

Comment: Scratch that I was just missing a bit but now works correctly

Comment: "around 8:30 when all the numbers started going negative" The only way that can happen is if you did not sort by date or if you have incorrect dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
Select calldate, 1 From cdr
Union
Select callend, -1 from cdr
Order by calldate
```

You then select the cumulative sum and then find the maximum. See [How to get running sum of a column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953294/how-to-get-running-sum-of-a-column-in-sql-server)