# sql server allocate payment to items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been scratching my head with this one for an hour still cannot seem to figure out a way to allocate Payment amount of $30 to the rows in the following table.

Given that i have the following items. Negative amount means the customer is in debt and owes us that amount. Now given that customer pays $30. We need to allocate that to the item.

```
ItemId                               amount sDATE
BD98E890-C7F8-47F4-9125-A68A88DD178D    -10 2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
7E047DE6-0DB7-4EDB-A751-C43BBD4610E5    -20 2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
5004AE1F-2A15-47E5-96FF-69A6C7D35521    -10 2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

for a payment of $30 the output should look like.

```
itemId                                   BeforeAllocation   AfterAllocation LeftToAllocate  sDate
BD98E890-C7F8-47F4-9125-A68A88DD178D    -10                 0               30              2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
7E047DE6-0DB7-4EDB-A751-C43BBD4610E5    -20                 0               20              2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
5004AE1F-2A15-47E5-96FF-69A6C7D35521    -10                 -10             0               2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

and if customer is paying partial amount for exmaple $25 the output should be.

```
    itemId                                   BeforeAllocation   AfterAllocation LeftToAllocate  sDate
    BD98E890-C7F8-47F4-9125-A68A88DD178D    -10                 0               25              2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
    7E047DE6-0DB7-4EDB-A751-C43BBD4610E5    -20                 -5              15              2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    5004AE1F-2A15-47E5-96FF-69A6C7D35521    -10                 -10             0               2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

Code:

```
Create table #temp(ItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , amount INT, sDATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #temp
        ( ItemId, 
          amount, 
          sDATE )
VALUES (  NEWID(),-10,'2016-01-04' ),
       (  NEWID(),-20,'2016-01-05' ), 
       (  NEWID(),-10,'2016-01-06' ) 


SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'BD98E890-C7F8-47F4-9125-A68A88DD178D' itemId, -10 BeforeAllocation, 0 AfterAllocation, 30 LeftToAllocate, '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000' sDate     
UNION
SELECT '7E047DE6-0DB7-4EDB-A751-C43BBD4610E5' itemId, -20 BeforeAllocation, 0 AfterAllocation, 20 LeftToAllocate, '2016-01-05 00:00:00.000' sDate
UNION
SELECT '5004AE1F-2A15-47E5-96FF-69A6C7D35521' itemId, -10 BeforeAllocation, -10 AfterAllocation,0 LeftToAllocate, '2016-01-06 00:00:00.000' sDate
)s
ORDER BY sdate

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'BD98E890-C7F8-47F4-9125-A68A88DD178D' itemId, -10 BeforeAllocation, 0 AfterAllocation, 25 LeftToAllocate, '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000' sDate     
UNION
SELECT '7E047DE6-0DB7-4EDB-A751-C43BBD4610E5' itemId, -20 BeforeAllocation, -5 AfterAllocation, 15 LeftToAllocate, '2016-01-05 00:00:00.000' sDate
UNION
SELECT '5004AE1F-2A15-47E5-96FF-69A6C7D35521' itemId, -10 BeforeAllocation, -10 AfterAllocation,0 LeftToAllocate, '2016-01-06 00:00:00.000' sDate
)s
ORDER BY sdate
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate an expression BeforeAllocationRT, to record the **r**unning **t**otal of BeforeAllocation (i.e. the sum of BeforeAllocation for this row and all preceding rows). If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later you can use window functions, otherwise you need a clumsy subexpression - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953294/how-to-get-running-sum-of-a-column-in-sql-server) for exact instructions.
2. Calculate an expression for the amount to allocate

   ```
   SELECT Allocation = CASE
       WHEN BeforeAllocationRT + @Payment > 0
           -- pay full amount for this item
           THEN -@BeforeAllocation
       WHEN BeforeAllocationRT + @Payment > @BeforeAllocation
           -- pay partial amount for this item
           THEN -(@BeforeAllocationRT+@Payment)
       ELSE
           -- pay nothing for this item
           0
       END
    , ...
   ```
3. Calculate expressions for `AfterAllocation` and `LeftToAllocate`.

   ```
   SELECT
       AfterAllocation = BeforeAllocation + Allocation
       ,LeftToAllocate = CASE WHEN BeforeAllocationRT+@Payment>0 THEN @Payment-BeforeAllocationRT ELSE 0 END
       ,...
   ```
4. Combine steps 1,2,3 using CTEs or subexpressions.

Disclaimer: I don't have access to a SQL Server instance right now, so none of this is tested.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DECLARE @PaidAmout INT = 30

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ItemId, amount, sDATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sDATE) AS RowNo
    FROM #temp 
),
Amount AS
(
    SELECT ItemId, 
            RowNo, 
            amount AS BeforeAllocation, 
            0 AS AfterAllocation, 
            @PaidAmout AS LeftToAllocate, 
            sDATE, 
            @PaidAmout + Amount AS LeftAmount 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE RowNo = 1

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.ItemId, 
            c.RowNo, 
            c.amount AS BeforeAllocation, 
            CASE WHEN a.LeftAmount + c.Amount < 0 THEN a.LeftAmount + c.Amount ELSE 0 END AS AfterAllocation, 
            CASE WHEN a.LeftAmount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE a.LeftAmount END AS LeftToAllocate, 
            c.sDATE, 
            a.LeftAmount + c.Amount AS LeftAmount 
    FROM CTE c
    INNER JOIN Amount a ON a.RowNo + 1 = c.RowNo 
) 

SELECT ItemId, 
        BeforeAllocation, 
        AfterAllocation, 
        LeftToAllocate, 
        sDATE
FROM Amount
```