# How can I make a total sum for rows that have the same accname account in SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I'm trying to run a query that will tell me total sum (credit) of each same item that enter in the same month and have the same mainacc, subacc. The reason I have multiple lines for the same item and no total sum

```
SELECT MovingBudget.mainacc, MovingBudget.subacc, MovingBudget.accname, MovingBudget.movingbudgetmony, ChequeRecord.credit,ChequeRecord.docdate,                        DATEDIFF(MM,ChequeRecord.docdate, GETDATE()),    DATEDIFF(YY,ChequeRecord.docdate, GETDATE()),
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, ChequeRecord.docdate, GETDATE()) =0 THEN ChequeRecord.credit END)  AS monthmove, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, ChequeRecord.docdate, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN ChequeRecord.credit END) AS modawer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, ChequeRecord.docdate, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN ChequeRecord.credit END) AS summation

               FROM  
                ChequeRecord INNER JOIN
                MovingBudget 
                ON ChequeRecord.accname = MovingBudget.accname
    WHERE 
    (SUBSTRING(MovingBudget.mainacc, 1, 1) = '1') 
    AND (SUBSTRING(MovingBudget.subacc, 1, 1) = '1') 

    GROUP BY MovingBudget.mainacc, MovingBudget.subacc, MovingBudget.accname, MovingBudget.movingbudgetmony, ChequeRecord.credit,ChequeRecord.docdate;
```

I can not come up with a SELECT query that will get me the total sum  for each item. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I added image to show the context but it contains arabic words only:

[image]

Comment: your `GROUP BY` depends on your columns mentioned in `SELECT`. For e.g. `Select column1(least unique), sum(ItemColumn(most unique)) from table group by column1,ItemColumn`  your item column has to be the column which has most unique so the group by finalize grouping based on items instead of any other column.

Answer (score 0):

for basic grouping this should be it.

```
select mainacc, subacc, datepart(month,docdate), sum(credit) from myTable group by mainacc, subacc, datepart(month,docdate)
```

But I have a feeling you are looking for running value calculation. In that case check this topic [How to get running sum of a column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953294/how-to-get-running-sum-of-a-column-in-sql-server)